# Get uploaded file location from Auth class in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel 5.3 with Laraadmin. I would like to show uploaded profile file instead of Gravatar in header navbar. With this code:

**notifs.blade.php**

```
{{ Auth::user()->photo }}
```

But I only get the id of uploaded photo.

**LATER EDIT**: I see that I have to use this:

```
use App\Models\Upload;
$img = Upload::find( Auth::user()->photo );
$img->path();
```

But I don't know where to insert it in order to get in my blade views the file path...
I found one [question same as mine](https://github.com/dwijitsolutions/laraadmin/issues/130), but the answer is not clear in a programming way.

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass `$img` as a template variable. Then you will be able to use all possible methods on it.

Comment: Hello Wolen. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the User model, or whichever you've defined as the Auth model, I would suggest creating a function like this:

```
public function profilePhotoPath() 
{
    $img = Upload::find($this->photo);
    return $img->path();
}
```

You can then reference this in the Blade template:

`<img src="{{ Auth::user()->profilePhotoPath }}">`

NOTE: The above will only work around the assumption that the user has set a photo. The PHP will need to be modified to handle no photo.

Comment: Hello mbzowood. Where should I insert your method? IDK which file handle Auth::user in order to insert there ...

Comment: @Andrew if you havent changed the authentication, it will be the `App\Users` model. To be sure, check the config/auth.php file and look for the model in the providers array. Mines on line 70 and reads: `'model' => App\Models\User::class,`

Answer (score 0):

If others are interested regarding this situation, I solved my issue with this code in my blade view file:

```
{{ App\Models\Upload::find( Auth::User()->photo )->path() }}
```